# Mongodb Atlas Express.js Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: mongodb, express

I want to connect my express app to my mongoDb Atlas cluster.
I'm from Iran, and cloud databases are sanctioned for us. I used VPN to bypass it in order to be able to practice.
Is there some coding mistake that I've done or is it because of using VPN?

The error:

```
(node:9008) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

connected

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
is listening...

    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1448:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

And the code:

```
database.js
----------------

const mongoDb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongoDb.MongoClient;

let _db;

const mongoConnect = callback => {
  MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://<someUser>:<somePassword>@<someCluster>-zh1eb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
  )
    .then(client => {
      console.log('\nconnected\n');
      _db = client.db();
      callback();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('\nerror\n', err);
      throw err;
    });
};

const getDb = () => {
  if (_db) {
    return _db;
  }
  throw 'NO DATABASE FOUND';
};

exports.mongoConnect = mongoConnect;
exports.getDb = getDb;




app.js
------------

...
const mongoConnect = require('./util/database').mongoConnect;
...

mongoConnect(() => {
  app.listen(3000, '\nis listening...\n');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem:

```
mongoConnect(() => {
  app.listen(3000, '\nis listening...\n');
});
```

should actually be

```
mongoConnect(() => {
  app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('\nis listening...\n');});
});
```

Silly me... :)

For those having such issue:
first check out whether the source of problem is your code or the connection to MongoDb.
That is instead of choosing "connect your application" select **"connect with Mongodb Compass"**.
If the Mongodb Compass could connect and show your cluster, then definitely there is something wrong with your code, esp. how it's coded to connect.